# How do i subtract a np vector from a numpy matrix if they have the same size leading dimension: matrix.shape[0] = len(vector)?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, vector

I want to do this:

```
>>> v = np.array([1,1,3])
>>> M = np.ones((len(v), 2, 2))
>>> M - v
```

So that v[0] is subtracted from all 4 values in M[0],
v[1] is subtracted from all the values in M[1] etc.
But I get an error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2,2) (3,)
```

To be clear I am looking for something equivalent to:

```
for i, n in enumerate(v): M[i] -= n
>>> M
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.]],

   [[-2., -2.],
    [-2., -2.]]])
```

But without a loop and time efficient

Extra points for: What is going on here? Is there something ambiguous about M - v? If not why doesn't numpy figure this out?

Comment: Also  https://docs.scipy.org is down right now  according to http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic broadcasting rule is that it can automatically add a dimension at the start, but you have to explicitly add ones at the end.  This avoids ambiguity.

```
(3,) + (2,) => (3,2) or (2,3)???    ambiguous
(3,1) + (2,) => (3,1)+ (1,2) => (3,2)
```

In your case:

```
(3,2,2) (3,1,1) => (3,2,2)

M + v[:,None, None]
```

I suppose `numpy` could deduce that (3,) can only be broadcast with (3,2,2) by adding dimensions at the end.  But what if `M` was (3,3,3)?  The developers chose a simpler, unambiguous rule.  It's not that hard for programmers to learn and use it.

And there's no harm it adding the explicit `v[None,:]` yourself.  As with grouping (), the explicit route often adds clarity - to the programmer if not to the interpreter.